# Missing 3D printing category tab in tool shelf after activating the addon

Tags: add-on

I've activated the Mesh-3D printing Toolbox in Blender. But the tab doesn't show up in the tool shelf. Please help, a bit urgent.

Thank you

What I have
[image: What I have]
What it should be:
[image: What it should be]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? This would help getting a faster and better answer as your question is somewhat unclear.

Comment: I refreshed, saved user settings, disabled, enabled again (nothing disappear, or appeared), saved user settngs again, everything. Also, when I close and reopen the program, the addon is still enabled, but no tab in the toolshelf.

Answer (score 3):

The panel for the 3D printing tools is only visible when the [active object](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/object/selecting.html) is a mesh object. The active object is the one highlighted in a slightly lighter colour (depending on the theme used).

There are times when an active object can be deleted or deselected without a new object being set as active, usually this happens using the outliner or a script.

Change your selection or <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> select one of your selected mesh objects to make it the active one so that the panel shows up.